# Manipulating axis labels in ggplot2 facet plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I produced some kind of "pyramid plot" or "back to back plot" to compare two groups and examine the proportion of a certain event in each group (in this example the administering of certain drugs).
I am 90% of the way there thanks to the `ggh4x`-package enabling me to mirror the scales. This is the code I used to produce the first plot below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

data <- data.frame(group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2"),
                   administered = c("no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
                   medication = c("DRUG A with a long name", "DRUG A with a long name", "DRUG A with a long name", "DRUG A with a long name", "DRUG B", "DRUG B", "DRUG B", "DRUG B", "DRUG C", "DRUG C", "DRUG C", "DRUG C"),
                   count = c(100,200,50,88,99,300,77,45,12,0,9,27))

ggplot(data, aes(x = medication,
                 y = count,
                 fill = administered)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  ylab("proportion") +    
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("no"="#FF0000FF",
                               "yes"="#0000FFFF"))+
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap2(~ group, scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(y = list(
  scale_y_reverse(labels = scales::percent),
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Result from my code]

I would like to get rid of the labels in the first facet and centre the labels between the first and second facets. My desired result is something like this:

[image: The photoshopped result I would like to achieve.]

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved via `ggh2x`  as well. Note first that I switched the `x` and `y` aes to get rid of the `coord_flip`.  As with the x axis you could  sepcify the y-axis for each facet too and position the one for the frist facet on the right. Afterwards you could get rid of the right y scale via `theme` options. To center the axis text use `hjust` for the left y scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data, aes(y = medication,
                 x = count,
                 fill = administered)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  labs(x = "proportion") +    
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("no"="#FF0000FF",
                               "yes"="#0000FFFF"))+
  facet_wrap2(~ group, scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(x = list(
    scale_x_reverse(labels = scales::percent),
    scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)),
    y = list(
      scale_y_discrete(position = "right"),
      scale_y_discrete())) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(hjust = .5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I would add `labels = \(x){stringr::str_wrap(x, width = 15)}`  to the second `scale_y_discrete`, to control the long name.

Comment: Thank you so much, @stefan. This is precisely what I needed. And thanks to you, as well, Arthur. Forgot to mention that feature request in my initial post :-)